# Absolute Action URL returning http://hostname:port:port/ in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, absolute-path

The following `UrlHelper` extension method to get an absolute URL for an MVC action incorrectly returns an URL in the format `http://hostname:port:port/`, e.g. `http://localhost:43256:43256/Job/Details`.

```
public static string AbsoluteAction(this UrlHelper url, string actionName,
                                    string controllerName, object routeValues)
{
        Uri requestUrl = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
        return url.Action(actionName,
                          controllerName,
                          new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues),
                          requestUrl.Scheme,
                          requestUrl.Authority);
}
```

Why is outputting a redundant port number? Is it `requestUrl.Authority`?

Comment: `Request.Url.Authority` does do a reachback through DNS... It probably is the issue. Why not `Request.Url.Host`?

Comment: @da7rutrak Request.Url.Host only contains the host name, but not the port. The issue seems to only occur on localhost and not on a deployed port 80 application.

Comment: I'm sorry - I assumed you would have combined it with `Request.Url.Port`